# An exception of type 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll ... 'Login failed for user 'SA'.'

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database running as a Docker container on a Mac.
I have been able to connect to it from DBeaver with the following credentials which I supplied while running the container:

[image]

But when I ry to run the application connecting to it with the following connection string:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost,1433; Initial Catalog=BaxiDigitalBankingCore20200115062255_local; Persist Security Info=False;User ID=SA;Password=CDL_BaxiCore2022;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

}

I get the following error

> Exception has occurred: CLR/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
> An exception of type 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Login failed for user 'SA'.'
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
> at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.b__0(DateTime giveUp)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext c, TState s) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.Migrate(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)
> at BaxiDigitalBanking.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext, DbReadonlyContext readonlyDbContext, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, RedisService redisService, RabbitMQService rabbitMQService, UserManager`1 userManager, RoleManager`1 roleManager, ISignUpBonusService signUpBonusService) in /Users/mac/Documents/Projects/CDL/BAXI/baxi-core/baxi-core/Startup.cs:line 409
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.d__31.MoveNext()

Any guide to resolve this will be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps the system databases of the instance are case-sensitive. Have you tried using the username of `sa` instead of `SA`?

Comment: I've tried changing the cases but still same issue persists

Comment: On the Docker console of the sqlserver container do you see any login messages with Error 18456? Compare their State number with those listed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) for more information about why the login failed.

Comment: Are you sure the `SA` **Login** is enabled on your server?...you can login to your server via SSMS with a different admin account to check on it, or try logging in directly as `SA` and if it fails that could be the reason.

Comment: @J.D. I have successfully logged in with those credentials through dbeaver which is an equivalent of SSMS on Mac. SSMS won't work on Mac but dbeaver is the equivalent. So, SA login is obviously enabled and the credentials are correct

Comment: Your DBeaver screenshot shows that the login is currently accessing the `master` database and because the Databases item is collapsed we can't see what other databases are there. Does the `BaxiDigitalBankingCore20200115062255_local` database already exist inside the Docker instance?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the database does not exist yet but I am running a .Net application which is expected to create the database when I run the migration. The Master you see there is the server, not the database and the user is expected to have access to the server and thus can create the database with the tables when migration is run. So, what is missing is the user's access to that server from my code as expected

Comment: Well you can't connect to a database before it exists. You should be able to connect to any of the system databases (master, model, msdb or tempdb) and create your new user database from that connection, though.

Comment: AlwaysLearning is correct. A database needs to exist before you can connect to it. Use the `master` database to connect to first, then create your database, then open a new connection to your new database.